# 2 Acciones en formulario PHP en Action y Submit

Tags: php, formularios, paypal

Quiero que cuando den clic en el botón enviar, se active el

```
<form  action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
```

Pero al mismo tiempo al dar clic en el botón enviar necesito que me aloje una información en la base de datos.
**El problema:** Si quito la propiedad action me activa la opción isset($_POST['submit'] y me graba en la base de datos, pero si coloco info en el action como se vé arriba no me toma nunca la opción submit

```
<form  action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"> 
    <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. --> 
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="sb-xxxxxx@business.example.com"> 
    <!-- Specify a Subscribe button. --> 
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions"> 
    <!-- Identify the subscription. --> 
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Membresía Premium"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="P-89A46836SU4380639MHGLS3Y"> 
    <!-- Set the terms of the regular subscription. --> 
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="10.00"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
     <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M"> 
     <input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="<?php $liga ?>">
     <!-- Set recurring payments until canceled. --> 
     <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">      
<!-- Retorna Información de PAgo -->
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="es_ES">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="image_url" value="https://betsolverpro.com/premium/assets/img/logoo.png">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?= $baseUrl ?>/receptor.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?= $baseUrl ?>/pago_cancelado.php">
     <!-- Display the payment button. -->
      <input type="submit" name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribe_LG.gif" alt="Subscribe">
       <img alt="" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" > 
       </form>
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    $consulta2 = "select max(idMembresia) + 1 as hola from membresia";
    
                        $result = mysqli_query($conex, $consulta2);
                        $fecha2 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                        $fecha3 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($fecha2."+ 30 days")); 

                        while ($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                            echo "<script>console.log('Console1111: sss );</script>";
                            $liga = $mostrar['hola'];
                            $sql="INSERT INTO membresia(idUsuarios, fechaInicial, fechaCorte,estado) 
                                                VALUES ('$idusu','$fecha2','$fecha3','1')";
                             mysqli_query($conex,$sql);     
echo "<script>console.log('Console1111: $liga - $fecha2 - $fecha3 - $idusu' );</script>";
?>        
         <?php
        }
```

Comment: Considera usar Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript para esto. Podrás pasar lo que quieras, cargar o dejar de cargar lo que quieras y además podrás actualizar la página sin tener que recargarla.

Comment: Debes hacerlo en dos procesos, el primero para guardar la membresía en la base de datos y el segundo para realizar el pago. Busca ejemplos en el [SDK de Paypal](https://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/)